# Makefile dependency when creating shared library links

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries

In a project I have an already created shared library called, let's say, 'myshare'. The library is already created as 'libmyshare.so.1.0.0' and its location is relative to the makefile at a relative address of 'adir/lib'.

In the makefile I want to create symbolic links for the shared library with the names 'libmyshare.so.1' and 'libmyshare.so'. In order to do this in the makefile I have these lines:

```
MYSHAREL = ./adir/lib/libmyshare.so.1.0.0
MYSHAREL1 = ./adir/lib/libmyshare.so.1
MYSHAREL2 = ./adir/lib/libmyshare.so
MYSHARELIBS = $(MYSHAREL) $(MYSHAREL1) $(MYSHAREL2)

.PHONY: all
all: myexetarget

myexetarget : various_files $(MYSHARELIBS)
    various_commands_to_make_target

$(MYSHAREL1): $(MYSHAREL)
    @echo "Creating symbolic link $(MYSHAREL1)"
    @ln -s $(MYSHAREL) $(MYSHAREL1)

$(MYSHAREL2): $(MYSHAREL)
    @echo "Creating symbolic link $(MYSHAREL2)"
    @ln -s $(MYSHAREL) $(MYSHAREL2)
```

When I run the 'make' command the links to the shared library are always created even when they already exist and even when the date of the shared library is prior to the date of already created symbolic links. Furthermore when I try to actually link to the shared library in my target, despite an `-L./adir/lib` and `-lmyshare` options among the linker options ( not shown above ) the link fails with:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmyshare
```

Both these problems lead me to believe that I am not specifying the name or relative location of the shared library correctly for the makefile processing to understand it. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: GNUMake 3.8.1 does not seem to recognize a symbolic link as an existing file. as for why you linking fails, you must give us a reproducible example.

Comment: By default, GNU make does not consider the modification time of a symbolic link. It considers the modification time of whatever it points to (but the `-L` option changes this). What do you mean with _links to the shared library are always created even when they already exist_? How do you know that they are recreated? And finally, how do you build your shared library? None of the rules you show builds it.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `ln -s` is probably the cause of your problem. If, from your top directory you execute:

```
ln -s ./adir/lib/libmyshare.so.1.0.0 ./adir/lib/libmyshare.so.1
```

(which is what your make rule does) a symbolic link is created in `./adir/lib`, named `libmyshare.so.1` and pointing to `./adir/lib/libmyshare.so.1.0.0`:

```
$ cd ./adir/lib
$ ls -l
libmyshare.so.1 -> ./adir/lib/libmyshare.so.1.0.0
libmyshare.so.1.0.0
```

So, `./adir/lib/libmyshare.so.1` actually points to `./adir/lib/adir/lib/libmyshare.so.1.0.0` that does not exist.

You can replace your `ln -s` command by:

```
@ln -sr $(MYSHAREL) $(MYSHAREL1)
```

Same for `MYSHAREL2`. The `-r` option of `ln` create symbolic links relative to link location.